# How to customize Primevue component Overlaypanel?

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I'm using the primevue component Overlaypanel on my Vue 3 project. It works fine, but I want to change its behavior.

Depending on the position of the page, it opens above or below the button I've placed to open it.

I want it to always open below the button, regardless of the content being cut off the screen, but I can't find how.

Also, I want to change its css styles, for example to show a picture without spaces between the content and the border of the overlay.

I tried changing the component or its styles attached, but I couldn't modify it at all.

The classes p-overlaypanel or p-overlaypanel-content shown in the primevue website didn't change the css properties, even when I used ::v-deep() on the style tag.